# Java MQ, what is closest to message queue in .Net platform?

Tags: c#, mq

What is .Net world that represent Java MQ (Message Queue? I am trying to figure out what is the technology that comes close to MQ in dot net world. I see widespred use of this technology on legacy application at work. 
Thanks

Comment: MSMQ would be my guess: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Java MQ"

Comment: If it isn't MSMQ you're searching for, perhaps [this](http://hoonzis.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/consuming-wcf-services-with-java-client.html) may be related?